# List is null after deserializing JSON from web URL

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to get data (vacancies) in JSON format from a web url into object(s) in C# so I can do other stuff with it.

Main.cs

```
String rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString("the_url");
VacancyCollection vacancyCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VacancyCollection>(rawJSON);
Console.WriteLine(vacancyCollection.vacancies.Count);
```

Vacancy Class:

```
class Vacancy
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

VacancyCollection Class:

```
class VacancyCollection
{
    public List<Vacancy> vacancies { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at ListFW.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\myName\source\repos\ListFW\ListFW\Program.cs:line 39

While debugging I can tell that in rawJSON the data sits properly, however for some mysterious reason even though this is exactly what is shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XssLaKDRV4Y  it doesn't work as it is shown there.

JSON example:

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": "P627",
      "title": "job title1",
      "url": "https://www.site.extension/job/159357"
    },
    {
      "id": "P628",
      "title": "job title2",
      "url": "https://www.site.extension/job/139900"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add json string you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: {
  "jobs": [
    {
      "id": "P627",
      "title": "job title1",
      "url": "https://www.site.extension/job/159357"
    },
    {
      "id": "P628",
      "title": "job title2",
      "url": "https://www.site.extension/job/139900"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Im saying that json wont map to the property "vacancies"

Comment: One thing that might help is using a website that will convert your JSON message to a C# class for you. This should at least help to make sure your class is defined correctly to match the JSON. https://jsonutils.com/ is one of them

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `VacancyCollection` class the list is called `vacancies` whereas in the JSON it is `jobs`.  The deserializer does not know that you intend for these to be mapped unless you tell it somehow.  You can either change the name of the property to match the JSON (or vice versa), or better yet add a `[JsonProperty]` attribute in your class to indicate the mapping like this:

```
class VacancyCollection
{
    [JsonProperty("jobs")]
    public List<Vacancy> vacancies { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3hnkhn